# EF & Linq unable to retrieve related data

Tags: c#, linq, serialization, linq-to-xml, entity-framework-6

I have the current entity class `Timesheet`:

```
public class Timesheet
{
    #region Properties
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Supplier { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Navigation Properties
    [ForeignKey("ProjectId")]
    public virtual Project CurrentProject { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AccountId")]
    public virtual Account CurrentAccount { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

When executing this simple query,

```
var query = db.Timesheets.AsQueryable();
var data = query;
return data;
```

I get the following results (note **CurrentProject** and **CurrentAccount**):

```
<Timesheet>
    <AccountId>33</AccountId>
    <CurrentAccount i:nil="true"/>
    <CurrentProject i:nil="true"/>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <ProjectId>1064</ProjectId>
    <Supplier>Test Supplier</Supplier>
    <TransactionDate>2016-02-27T00:00:00</TransactionDate>
</Timesheet>
```

However, when trying to explicitly load related objects,

```
var query = db.Timesheets.AsQueryable();
var data = query.Include(n => n.CurrentProject);
return data;
```

I get a serialization error:

> The 'ObjectContent 1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'
>
> `<ExceptionMessage>`Type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Timesheet_B61B0CCFFB38C448231EBA3EF4D3D57C851AD2AE97FAA0BF8AA7F175D4C507D6' with data contract name 'Timesheet_B61B0CCFFB38C448231EBA3EF4D3D57C851AD2AE97FAA0BF8AA7F175D4C507D6:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.`</ExceptionMessage>`

I ran a similar query using `LINQPad` and got correct results with all the related objects so I don't know what's wrong here.

I'm a n00b here and can really use your help!

Comment: Are you doing this in WCF or Web API? The error is about serialization and not EF

Comment: @PraveenPaulose data is being retrieved/returned via Web API

Comment: You've retrieved the data fine.  You are having an issue serializing it after you've gotten it.

Comment: @RobertMcKee How do I resolve the serialization issue so that the consuming client application can traverse the data being returned?

Comment: Did you try adding a `KnownTypeAttribute`?

Comment: The easiest way is to create a view model independently from the data model, and to use LINQ to select into that view model, then serialize that.  Then you can put any and all serialization stuff you need into it, and remove the virtual navigation properties which is usually a pain point since they are circular.  You might be able to reuse the data model by placing just the right attributes on it, but I'm not sure which ones myself.  You might try this article to help: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#handling_circular_object_references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's almost certainly due to a navigation property from Project back to the Timesheet.

When Timesheet is being serialized, so is the CurrentProject property. That, in turn, references the Timesheet, resulting in a circular reference.

Decorate the Timesheet navigation property on Project class to prevent it being serialized: `[JsonIgnore]`. You'll have to do the same with the Account class if you .Include() that, too.

Comment: @StevenMorgan I created a `DTO` to only return data that was needed. That seemed to work for a moment, but all of a sudden it is throwing the same error again. Interestingly enough, it works if I return it as a `List<Timesheet>` instead of an `IQueryable`. Do you think this is still related to some circular reference?

Comment: Was the db context instance that you queried against a local variable or a field of the controller class? If it's a local variable, it will go out of scope when the action completes, so when the serializer attempts to serialize the object, the deferred database call fails.